# jQuery fadeIn ease

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, jquery-easing

I use below jQuery script to fade in my dropdown-menu. How do I use `easing` in this example?

```
  $('ul.navbar-nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(50);
  }, 
  function() {
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(50);
  });
```

Comment: Have you tried `.fadeIn({duration:50,easing:"swing"})`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in [jQuery fadeIn documentation](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/),

> As of jQuery 1.4.3, an optional string naming an easing function may
>   be used. Easing functions specify the speed at which the animation
>   progresses at different points within the animation. The only easing
>   implementations in the jQuery library are the default, called `swing`,
>   and one that progresses at a constant pace, called `linear`. More easing
>   functions are available with the use of plug-ins, most notably the
>   [jQuery UI suite](http://jqueryui.com/).

Here is the syntax

```
$(selector).fadeIn(speed,easing,callback)
```

Here is an example

```
$(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(500,"linear");
```

Answer (score 0):

fadeIn() method has 3 parameters. You can pass easing parameter to fadeIn() function.

fadeIn() syntax:

```
$(selector).fadeIn(speed,easing,callback)
```

Change your code from:

```
$(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(50);
```

To:

```
$(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(50,"Easing Type");
```

For more details check fadeIn() method:

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_fadein.asp

Comment: sorry a possible duplicate answer? (17 seconds late)

Answer (score 0):

> $(selector).fadeIn(speed,easing,callback)
>
> $(selector).fadeOut(speed,easing,callback)

To use different easing options in jQuery fadeIn/fadeOut, you need to fill in the second parameter

**Example:**

```
$(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(50,'linear',function(){});
```

---

The existing ease option for jQuery will be **swing** and **linear**. If you need more options you will need to use [jQuery UI suite](http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/)

From jQuery [fadeIn documentation](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/)

> Easing
>
> As of jQuery 1.4.3, an optional string naming an easing function may be used. Easing functions specify the speed at which the animation progresses at different points within the animation. The only easing implementations in the jQuery library are the default, called swing, and one that progresses at a constant pace, called linear. More easing functions are available with the use of plug-ins, most notably the jQuery UI suite.

Comment: I post my answer before you, that makes me the duplicates!?